# how to sort values from a dictionary in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm just starting to learn python. We were told about data types (integer, float, boolean), and also about sets, strings, lists etc. A little more about cycles (for/while). In my homework I need code which returns a filtered list of geo_logs containing only visits from India.

I need to do this without difficult functions, alpha or something like that. Only standard cycles.

```py
geo_logs = [
    {'visit1': ['Moscow', 'Russia']},
    {'visit2': ['Delhi', 'India']},
    {'visit3': ['Bangalore', 'India']},
    {'visit4': ['Lisbon', 'Portugal']},
    {'visit5': ['Paris', 'France']},
    {'visit6': ['Mumbai', 'India']},
]

for visit in geo_logs:
    if visit.values() == 'India':
        print(visit.values())
```

but this does not return anything.

If possible, write a code and explain it. I want to understand how python works, and not just do homework.

Comment: `for visit in geo_logs: if  'India' in visit.values(): print(visit.values()` essentially iterating over list of dictionaroes, checking for India via in operator on the values of the dictionary and printing the dictionary values if present `visit.values() == 'India'` is comparing a values view to a string, which will never be True

Comment: moreover `visit.values()` will return `dict_values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.values()` returns a list of all the values in the entire dictionary.  Since your values are already a list, now you have a list-of-list, like `[['Delhi', 'India']]`

Obviously, `[['Delhi', 'India']]` does not equal `'India'`.

Try `if 'India' in list(visit.values())[0]` instead.

This data structure is a bit confusing -- why do you have different keys `visit1`, `visit2` etc. when the data is in separate dictionaries anyway?  Either make them all have the same key `visit`, or combine them into one large dictionary.

Comment: This results in `if 'India' in visit.values()[0]:
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: This is a difference between Python 2 and Python 3.  I'll rework my answer.

Comment: Updated to wrap `visit.values()` in a `list()`.

Comment: "why do you have different keys visit1, visit2 etc. when the data is in separate dictionaries anyway"   This is my homework, not me. i can't remake this data

Comment: That works now in Python 3. The OP's `print(visit.values())` will yield output rows like `dict_values([['Delhi', 'India']])` so you might (or might not) want to change it to  `print(list(visit.values())[0]) ` to yield an easier-on-the-eyes `['Delhi', 'India']`

Comment: [0] is dictionary index, right? this out visit1, visit2 problem i can call [visit] instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for visits in geo_logs:
  for visit,[City,Country] in visits.items():
    if Country == 'India':
      print (visits)
```

Comment: it looks like magic to me. 3 new variables and a loop in a loop?